# Any Way To Find An iPhone That Isn't Signed Into iCloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I lost my iPhone 6s that isn't signed into iCloud. So, in turn, I can't use 'find my iPhone' or call the iPhone, because I haven't yet assigned a phone number to it. I did sign into the phone, though. Just not iCloud. Is there any way to find my 6s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way would be the old-fashioned - go look for it, ask others if they've seen it, etc.

You don't specify what you mean by "signing into the phone" except that it is not iCloud, you've signed into. If the service you did sign into (for example Facebook Messenger?) does have some kind of location tracking, it might give you a last known position.

If you have just misplaced the phone, you can't really report it as stolen with Apple to get it blocked on cell networks.